# Make a container display:none when the content of <a> is empty

Tags: jquery, css, menu

Im trying to make the following with jQuery.

```
<ul><br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
<li>div>a><br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
</ul><br />
<br />
```

When the content of a> is empty the container li> needs to been on display none.

```
<br />
<ul><br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
<li class="hidden">div>a><br />
<li>div>a>menu item<br />
</ul><br />
```

can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets the css attibute 'display' to 'none' for all `li` tags which include an empty `a` tag:

```
$("ul a:empty").closest("li").css('display','none');
```

If you want to change the class of the `li` to hidden you could use:

```
$("ul a:empty").closest("li").addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: `.css('display', 'none')` is equivalent to `.hide()`.

Comment: I think `.hide()` method does not actually set the the css attribute 'display' to 'none'. Depending on OPs intention it might matter which method he uses.

Comment: This would hide *all* parent `<li>` elements, hiding entire trees if this was nested, you should use `.closest()` here, or `.parents()` with `:first` in older jQuery versions.

Comment: @Pit - Is *does* set `display: none;`, *and* it stores the previous `display` value for `.show()` to use...which may not be the default, so it's safer as well.

Comment: @Nick you're right I changed the `.parents()` to `.closest()`

Comment: @Nick you're right again.Only plus for `.css()` is that you actually see what the method changes if you don't know by heart the `.hide()`. But the possibility to use `.show()` afterwards might be plus for `.hide()`.

Comment: Thanx... Worked great... I used the .css

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector on the `<a>` and hide the `<li>`, using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$("ul a:empty").closest("li").hide();
```

or [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) like this:

```
$("ul li:has(a:empty)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

usually this would be done server side, with what ever server side language you use, this will grantee cross browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need to use jQuery.

I just found this thread searching for a solution to a similar issue, and just implemented and tested a fix in straight CSS with

```
ul a:empty {display:none !important;}
```

Tested with current versions of FF (22), IE (10), Chrome (30) and FWIW, windows version of Safari 5.1.7.

PS: this will work on any empty css selector. Demo using a div:empty in action at http://new.3blindmiceusa.com/products/window-blinds/wood/ in all my shadowbox pop-up windows.

All the images at the top have title elements on the href which are displayed as the title on the image, all the icons in sidebar for pop-up contact forms have no title so the title div with the background remains hidden.

(I know I could have coded this into a custom skin for shadowbox but I tried not to modify that code other than to add the social sharing widget on each photo)